# Oracle LIKE Not working

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to get my grips on Oracle from a SQL environment.
Does anyone know why this query returns 0?

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM MORGS.LOGS l
WHERE ( l.LOCATION = 'X:\Import\XXX006' ) AND
      ( l.DIRECTION = 'IN' ) AND
      ( 'XXX006-Test.txt' LIKE '%XXX006.D$Date,YYYYMMDD$.T$Date,HHNNSS$%' ) -- It fails on this condition
```

Please take note that 'XXX006-Test.txt' on the left handside of LIKE is the value of the column in the table. I've just hard-coded it here just to demo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should 'XXX006-Test.txt' match '%AAG006.D$Date,YYYYMMDD$.T$Date,HHNNSS$%'? What do you need to do?

Comment: Sorry, just edited now...I meant to hide the AAG bit from this forum...My main interest is to match the first part of the file name which is 'XXX006' on both sides, is this possible?

Comment: `LIKE` evaluates string matchings; for example, `'xxABxx'` IS LIKE `'%AB%'` and IS NOT LIKE `'%ABYYYYYYY%'`. Please post some sample of what logic you need to get from your query

Comment: `LIKE` clause is used for pure text match. Only wildcards it understand are `%` (for any number of characters) and `_` (for single character). Anything else in string is evaluated as is. In your case, 'xxx006-Test.txt' can match '%006%txt' or '%.txt' or '___006.txt' etc. If you need complex match, you must use regex matching functions of Oracle. more details https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually LIKE is working. I'm afraid it's your logic that's faulty. The premise of LIKE is that the whole text in the first parameter exists *in its entirety* in the second, with wildcards to omit irrelevant characters from the matching.

So this is TRUE ...

```
where 'ABC' like 'ABC%'
```

... and this is FALSE ...

```
where 'ABC' like 'ABCDEF'
```

Looking at your actual test:

```
( 'XXX006-Test.txt' LIKE '%XXX006.D$Date,YYYYMMDD$.T$Date,HHNNSS$%' )
```

we notice that the string `XXX006-Test.txt` does not exist in `XXX006.D$Date,YYYYMMDD$.T$Date,HHNNSS$` so LIKE quite rightly returns FALSE.

> " Do you know how I can split the RHS on a '.' and grab only the first index of the split results which is 'XXX006'?"

If the required match is always six characters long the simplest thing is

```
substr('XXX006-Test.txt', 1, 6)
```

If the leading thing is variable, you can use regular expressions. To extract everything before the dot:

```
 regexp_replace ( 'XXX006-Test.txt',  '(.+)\.txt$','\1'  )
```

Although given the values in the two strings you might want to match on the dash instead ...

```
 regexp_replace ( 'XXX006-Test.txt',  '([a-z0-9]+)\-(.*)','\1' )
```

Depends how stable the pattern is.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I was hoping that the first part on LHS 'XXX006' would manage to match the first part on the RHS 'XXX006' and ignore the rest of the string on either sides. Do you know how I can split the RHS on a '.' and grab only the first index of the split results which is 'XXX006'? If I can achieve that within a SELECT query I should be able to find a work around...